# Не работает код при открытии в другом браузере и не загружает информацию с HTTP страниц

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

У меня не работает скрипт сниффера пакетов, когда я использую MicrosoftEdge всё работает прекрасно, HTTP загружаются, но страница просто пустая (если это возможно, то объясните, почему так происходит. Как сделать так чтобы страницы открывались в HTTP, так как я понизил им уровень с HTTPS до HTTP). Ещё у меня возникает сложность, при использовании браузера Firefox мой скрипт перестает работать и выдаёт ошибку:

```py
def get_login_info(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = packet[scapy.Raw].load
        keywords = ['username', 'user', 'login', 'password', 'pass']
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in load:
                return load
```

> in get_login_info if keyword in load: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь ошибка не в логике, описанной в вопросе, а в том, что вы сравниваете два значения с разными типами данных.
Воспроизведу вашу ошибку

```py
keywords = ['username', 'user', 'login', 'password', 'pass']
load  = b"login may be or not, how can I check?"
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in load:
        print(f"Founded {keyword}")
```

Ну, и результат:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Из вашего кода абсолютно понятно, что вы имеете тип `str` для сущности `keyword`. А из ошибки можно сделать вывод, что сущность `load` имеет тип данных `bytes`. Для проверки всегда можно вывести их тип

```py
>>> type(load) 
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(keywords[0]) 
<class 'str'>
```

Как решить. Очевидно привести сравниваемые данные к одному типу. Метод `decode()` позволяет привести данные из байтовой последовательности к строке

```py
keywords = ['username', 'user', 'login', 'password', 'pass']
load  = b"login may be or not, how can I check?"
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in load.decode(): # здесь преобразование
        print(f"Founded: {keyword}")
```

Вывод

```
Founded: login
```

Это пример для понимания и нахождения ошибки. Естественно, `load` может содержать данные в другом виде. Покажу пример для `json`, который приходит в виде байтовой последовательности

```py
import json
keywords = ['username', 'user', 'login', 'password', 'pass']
load  = b'{"login":"loginsnts","user":"Bradly Cooper"}'
load_dict = json.loads(load)
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in load_dict.keys():
        print(f"Founded: {keyword}")
```

вывод

```
Founded: user
Founded: login
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю (ответ работоспобности кода напишу, #через Firefox), а ещё вопрос с тем что у меня не погружаются HTTP страницы, с учетом того что у меня включен SSLStrip, это можно как-то исправить (в терминале отображается открытая страница, но на машине она перестаёт загружаться, там просто белая страница)?